# Setting up softKeyboard example from the Android SDK getting errors

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, sample

I have tried every way I could find online to use the softKeyboard example from the SDK.  I have tried several different APIs.

I have tried `File -> New -> Other... -> Android Sample Project`

I have tried `File -> New -> Other... -> Android Project from Existing Code`

I have tried creating a new project and copying the files over

No matter what I have done, the resultant code is loaded with errors.  For example:

1. The import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSubtype cannot be resolved
2. The method getSubtypeCount() is undefined for the type InputMethodInfo
3. The method onPreferenceClick(Preference) of type new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){} must override a superclass method

There are many more.  I have gotten other samples to work with no problem.  I am missing something when it comes to importing these samples.  What is it?

Comment: Likely a problem with the way interface functions are now defined. Try deleting the `@Override` from the methods that are in error.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error too.

You have to select it from `File -> New -> Other...Android -> Android Sample Project`

Ensure you have selected the correct API level. Try doing a clean and build, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your android version more than 4.0
by Right click on project >properties > Android > select more than 4.0 version than apply.
And also change api level in AdroidManifest.xml file